# How to exclude some controls in a FOR EACH CONTROL Loop?

Tags: vb.net, controls

So I have a neat little function that I use to make sure only one checkbox can be checked inside a GroupBox.

This is what it looks like...

```
Private Sub ToggleCheckBoxOnEntry(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'This handles mutually exclusivity for the check boxes so that only one is ever allowed to be checked 
    Static CurrentlySelectedbox As CheckBox

    If CType(sender, CheckBox).Checked Then
        CurrentlySelectedbox = sender
    End If

    For Each cntrl As CheckBox In gbxReports.Controls
        If cntrl.Checked AndAlso cntrl.Name <> CurrentlySelectedbox.Name Then
            cntrl.Checked = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And for each checkBox_CheckChanged I include this line...

```
Private Sub chkReports_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ToggleCheckBoxOnEntry(sender, e)

End Sub
```

So I have this great looking groupbox with about 10 reports and it works great. The problem comes when I try to include a combobox for one of the extracts where I let the user select something from a drop down and use it as a parameter. I do not want to include it outside of the GroupBox (unless there's no way to fix my issue), however, if I include it inside of it I get an error..

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'.

Is there a way for me to exclude some controls from the loop such as

```
For each cntrl as CheckBox in gbxReports.controls // except comboboxes/ or only checkboxes??
```

The only controls that I would potentially have in the group box are checkboxes and comboboxes.

Comment: the easiest solution is to remove `as Checkbox` from your `foreach` and check inside the loop if the controls is  `checkbox` type before doing anything

Comment: If you only want to have one checkbox chosen at a time, why not use radio buttons in the groupbox instead? This way, only one can be checked at a time without you needing to write any code. Have a look here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you be specific to what you want to loop rather than the mix of Controls:

```
For Each chexkb As Checkbox In Controls.OfType(Of Checkbox)()
    'do the loop just on the check boxes
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. Under for Each cntrl i added an if statemnt IF TYPEOF cntrl is Checkbox

Comment: that is essentially the same thing however you have written more code to accomplish the same thing :)